# Magnifier glass and image alignment

Tags: html, css

I used the magnifier code from w3schools to create an HTML page. If I keep the image left aligned (i.e., on the left border), the magnifier works fine.  If I center the image however (my preference), the magnifier doesn't track with the image (it stays on the left).  Any idea how I can fix this problem?  The code is pasted below.  Thanks for any help- I'm a novice and this is driving me crazy.  Steve

```js
function magnify(imgID, zoom) {

  var img, glass, w, h, bw;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  /*create magnifier glass:*/
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");
  
  glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
  /*insert magnifier glass:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
  /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
  glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
  
  bw = 3;
  w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
  h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;
  
  /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
  glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);

  function moveMagnifier(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    x = pos.x;
    y = pos.y;
    /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {
      x = img.width - (w / zoom);
    }
    if (x < w / zoom) {
      x = w / zoom;
    }
    if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {
      y = img.height - (h / zoom);
    }
    if (y < h / zoom) {
      y = h / zoom;
    }
    
    /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
    glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
    /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
    glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
  }

  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0,
      y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    
    return {
      x: x,
      y: y
    };
  }
  
}

/* Initiate Magnify Function
with the id of the image, and the strength of the magnifier glass:*/
magnify("myimage", 3);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-magnifier-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-magnifier-glass {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: none;
  /*Set the size of the magnifier
glass:*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Magnifier Glass</h1>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>

<div style="text-align: center;" class="img-magnifier-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="http://www.starrywonders.com/infraredexample.jpg" alt="infraredexample" style="height: 500px; width: 800px;">
</div>

<p>Feel free to change the strength of the magnifier glass when initiating the magnify function.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, though you have moved the image centrally (by dint of text-align) you have not compensated for that in the positioning of the glass.

At its simplest the image has moved `window.innerWidth/2 - img.width/2` (not accounting for any possible padding or margins etc which may be there in a production page). The value of x for the glass is adjusted by this amount in this snippet.

```js
function magnify(imgID, zoom) {

  var img, glass, w, h, bw;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  /*create magnifier glass:*/
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");

  glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
  /*insert magnifier glass:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
  /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
  glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";

  bw = 3;
  w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
  h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;

  /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
  glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);

  function moveMagnifier(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    x = pos.x;
    y = pos.y;
    /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {
      x = img.width - (w / zoom);
    }
    if (x < w / zoom) {
      x = w / zoom;
    }
    if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {
      y = img.height - (h / zoom);
    }
    if (y < h / zoom) {
      y = h / zoom;
    }

    /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.left = (x - w + window.innerWidth / 2 - img.width / 2) + "px";
    glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
    /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
    glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
  }

  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0,
      y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;

    return {
      x: x,
      y: y
    };
  }

}

/* Initiate Magnify Function
with the id of the image, and the strength of the magnifier glass:*/
magnify("myimage", 3);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-magnifier-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-magnifier-glass {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: none;
  /*Set the size of the magnifier
glass:*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Magnifier Glass</h1>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>

<div style="text-align: center;" class="img-magnifier-container"> <img id="myimage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zTJn.jpg" alt="infraredexample" style="height: 500px; width: 800px;">
</div>

<p>Feel free to change the strength of the magnifier glass when initiating the magnify function.</p>
```

Comment: This is very helpful- you've pointed me in the right direction!  I really appreciate it.  Steve